# How do I adjust the hue (intensity) of GNOME Night Light?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, color-management, night-light

I tried to use GNOME Nightlight in Ubuntu 17.04. The settings only allow me to turn it on and adjust the time. Is it possible to adjust the intensity or temperature of the hue? Currently, it's a bit too much.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-temperature <temperature>
```

Here are some temperatures values I determined myself (probably not correct):

- `1000` Lowest value (really red)
- `4000` Default night light temperature
- `5500` More pleasant and less intense night light temperature
- `6500` Default temperature (night light off)
- `10000` Highest value (really blue)

Comment: This worked in ubuntu 18.04 also

Comment: Also confirming this has worked on Ubuntu 18.04. I found 5000 to be the sweet spot for me.

Comment: It would be great if we could adjust the brightness

Comment: I'm also using Ubuntu 18.04 but for me the above command doesn't have any effect, also not after switching the nightlight off and on again.  Any idea what's going wrong for me?

Comment: @stare.in.the.air what about the day temperature instead of the night light? Is there a way to list all possible temperature settings?

Comment: @Alfe Try without sudo! That was the case on my setup...

Comment: Great, thanks! On ubuntu 18.04.6 Gnome 3.28.2 the graphical tool to adjust color temperature was not working. With this command, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 21):

There's now a GNOME shell extension called "**Night Light Slider**" that works quite nicely:

> [Night Light Slider extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1276/night-light-slider/)
>
> [image: Night Light Slider extension demo]

In case you don't already have shell extensions running, here's a good overview of what to do: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)

Comment: Great extension, the little slider is just what I wanted. Works out of the box on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Answer (score 5):

To expand upon Bimsara Gayanga's answer regarding `dconf-editor`, here's how the process worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. First, install it ([source](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/dconf-editor)):

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y dconf-editor
```

Then, run `dconf-editor` on the command line. This will result in a GUI that you can click on. If you click on org -> gnome -> settings-daemon -> plugins -> color ([source](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/07/adjust-color-temperature-gnome-night-light)) then you will see the night light settings:

[image]

Then you can adjust the `night-light-temperature` tab. In fact, I also realized that you can use this to adjust the schedule. The GUI that we normally use with Ubuntu 18 was confusing me, and I wasn't able to get night light working on it. Fortunately, I could change the start time and end time here.

Answer (score 1):

Install dconf editor for ubuntu. You can do that using the software installer that comes with ubuntu.
Then search for "night"
Choose the tab for night light temperature.
Choose custome mode and set the value. I prefer already mentioned 5500. 4000 is too much for eye.