# How do I get the Redshift functionality of smart adjustment of the color temperature throughout the day in a Wayland session of Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, colors, 17.10, wayland, redshift

[Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) is a neat little program allowing you to adjust color temperature of the screen during the day and separately during the night. Is it possible to achieve this with GNOME 3 on Ubuntu 17.10?

Under Setting → Devices → Displays GNOME allows to enable **Night Light** which makes the screen somewhat warmer at night. However, it does not allow to adjust the color temperature, and it doesn't work during the day.

**How to replicate the Redshift functionality in Gnome 3 on Wayland?**

Comment: If you do not need Wayland for real, you can login to the *Ubuntu on Xorg* session and try redshift here.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks. I decided to go even a step further and run Unity for a while longer. From the same menu. Redshift still works there.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift/+bug/1431645 .  The wayland solution is nightlight - https://www.gnome.org/news/2017/03/gnome-3-24-released/attachment/night-light/

Answer (score 2):

Not really a good one but kinda half-baked solution is using a GNOME shell extension called "[Night Light Slider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1276/night-light-slider/)". It adds a slider to control the colour temperature manually:

[image]
(screenshot source: extension's homepage at extensions.gnome.org)

Also you may change Night Light's colour temperature using *dconf Editor*/`gsettings` as suggested here: [How to adjust the hue (intencity) of gnome night light?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914500/how-to-adjust-the-hue-intencity-of-gnome-night-light)

Comment: And nightlight - https://www.gnome.org/news/2017/03/gnome-3-24-released/attachment/night-light/

Comment: @Panther it's an extension for night light, it just adds a temperature slider for night light in the system menu. OP is aware of night light, they just want a more intelligent temperature shift option like redshift offers.

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR;

Just for the quick reader who didn't read the whole OP question:

Here is a screenshot of the Solution Ubuntu offers since 17.10, the built-in feature like redshift called "Night Light":

> The Night Light feature is extremely easy to enable. We just need to open Settings, and then go to Devices → Display. Here we need to move the button next to Night Light to the “on” position.

[image]

Source: https://pentruprieteni.com/en/how-to/how-to-enable-night-light-on-ubuntu-17-10/