# Make Ubuntu's Night Light look like Manjaro KDE's Night Color

Tags: kde, gnome-shell, colors, color-management, night-light

How can I make Ubuntu's Night Light look like Manjaro KDE's Night Color? I want this because Manjaro's Night Color has a lot more features that allows me to customize the settings the way I want.

Here is a screenshot of Ubuntu's Night Light:

[image: Ubuntu's Night Light]

Here are some screenshots of Manjaro KDE's Night Color:

[image: Manjaro KDE's Night Color - 2]
[image: Manjaro KDE's Night Color - 3]

As you can see, there are many more features in Manjaro KDE (can set a specific value to the color temperature, can make it always on, can set specific location)

**Note**:  I don't want to install `redshift` or `flux`. Please, don't suggest that. I have had a bad experience with those applications, such as bugs and crashes at random times.

**UPDATED**:

I know I can change the color temperature of Night Light in GNOME. Indeed, I'm already doing that. I typed a command in bash shell to set up the desirable temperature color. However, this is not an answer to my question. I'm **not** looking for ways to change the color temperature **only**. What I want is a nice GUI interface where I can do those things and more. I'm also aware of the `dconf-editor` application, which also allows to change the color of Night Light. But, as said before, this is not the only thing I'm searching for; I'm looking for something more user friendly.

Comment: I don't see screen brightness on either one? For example I have `intel_backlight` set to 850 at night and 3500 at day (where 0 is off and 7500 is max brightness. This varies by backlight manufacturer and model). Also your KDE doesn't say how many K is on the left, only on the right. For my system I use color temperature of 3500 K at night and 6500 K during the day on 4K TV but not as drastic on Sony TV which has better ambient light control. The laptop display is more like 4500K during night and 6500 K temperature during day. None of your packages control 3 monitors independently I might add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## eyesome

[Eyesome](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome) has more options to independently control your monitors (up to three) than either package. It's been released for three years with no changes but on June 2, 2020 a color temperature slider was added.

In addition to the documentation on the github page link above where you can download eyesome, additional documentation with screen shots is available here in Ask Ubuntu:

- [Set initial startup background brightness depending on daytime](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829814/set-initial-startup-background-brightness-depending-on-daytime/887249#887249)

---

### New features on June 2, 2020

Here are the new features published today on github:

[image: eyesome override.gif]

- The ***Get*** button retrieves gamma for one of three monitors' Day or Night settings. It then calculates Color Temperature based on gamma (Red:Green:Blue)
- The ***Color*** button presents a slider to select Color Temperature from 1000K to 10,000K (Kelvins). When selecting ***Convert*** the chosen temperature is converted to Gamma (Red:Green:Blue).
- The ***Preview*** button temporarily shows what the chose Color Temperature looks like on all monitors.
- The ***Apply*** button updates the chosen Monitor and Daytime / Nighttime setting with the last Color Temperature selected.

---

### Original features from 2017

Here's a few screenshots (of a dozen screens) to give you an idea about eyesome:

[image: eyesome configuration general tab.png]

[image: eyesome-edit-configuration-monitor-1.png]

[image]

---

### Reply to comment Color Temperature to Gamma

The new version has a Color to Gamma conversion table (bash syntax):

```bash
#                 Red         Green       Blue     Color Temperature
GammaRampArr=( 1.00000000  0.05181963  0.00000000   500 \
               1.00000000  0.18172716  0.00000000  1000 \
               1.00000000  0.42322816  0.00000000  1500 \
               1.00000000  0.54360078  0.08679949  2000 \
               1.00000000  0.64373109  0.28819679  2500 \
               1.00000000  0.71976951  0.42860152  3000 \
               1.00000000  0.77987699  0.54642268  3500 \
               1.00000000  0.82854786  0.64816570  4000 \
               1.00000000  0.86860704  0.73688797  4500 \
               1.00000000  0.90198230  0.81465502  5000 \
               1.00000000  0.93853986  0.88130458  5500 \
               1.00000000  0.97107439  0.94305985  6000 \
               1.00000000  1.00000000  1.00000000  6500 \
               0.95160805  0.96983355  1.00000000  7000 \
               0.91194747  0.94470005  1.00000000  7500 \
               0.87906581  0.92357340  1.00000000  8000 \
               0.85139976  0.90559011  1.00000000  8500 \
               0.82782969  0.89011714  1.00000000  9000 \
               0.80753191  0.87667891  1.00000000  9500 \
               0.78988728  0.86491137  1.00000000  10000 \
               0.77442176  0.85453121  1.00000000  10500 \
             )
# Temperatures of 500 & 10500 are not allowed. Provided for looping min-max.
```

---

### Reply to comments 2

This question was asked today:

> Is it possible to manually set eyesome to always run ? Regardless of
>   time. Also, is it possible to disable internet connection? Because if
>   it set to be always on, then there is no need to retrieve location
>   from the internet. Moreover, I don't like apps retrieving my location
>   or having access to the internet if they don't need to

You can forego using internet to get sunrise/sunset times with these commands:

```bash
sudo echo "7:00 am" > /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-sunrise
sudo echo "9:00 pm" > /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-sunset
```

Change the time appropriately. I'll look at changing the software in the next upgrade to make this easier.

Please note `eyesome` doesn't retrieve your location. You're merely keying your city name into the screen and it's stored on a configuration file on your disk. You aren't keying in your IP address or longitude / latitude like Redshift, Night Light or F.lux. BTW your city name is already known to every website you visit because they know your ISP Service Provider's city. Unless you are using a VPN of course.

Comment: I will git it a try. Could you also provide a url  to find one of these tables used to convert temperature color to RGB values? Thanks in advance

Comment: @StudentofScience I updated the answer with a table of Red:Green:Blue to Color Temperatures.

Comment: @StudentofScience I updated the answer with new features finished today. After a couple days of testing the github will be updated. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out probably today or tomorrow

Comment: Is it possible to manually set eyesome to always run ? Regardless of time. Also, is it possible to disable internet connection? Because if it set to be always on, then there is no need to retrieve location from the internet. Moreover, I don't like apps retrieving my location or having access to the internet if they don't need to

Comment: @StudentofScience I've updated answer with reply to your last comment of sunrise/sunset times retrieved by city name using internet. You definitely don't have to use the internet if you don't want to.

Comment: Thank you very much :) ! I marked your answer as the correct one

Comment: @StudentofScience Thank you for accepting answer. I've just updated github with latest version containing color temperature slider.

Comment: @StudentofScience Yesterday (June 2, 2020) github version wasn't uploaded with the most current version properly. It has just been uploaded again with the most current version.

Comment: It is me who needs to thank you for building such good work! :)

Comment: @StudentofScience Well stay tuned here or on the github I'm going to modify screens to input sunrise and sunset times manually. This also benefits if say dark storm clouds at 3:00pm just change sunset to 2:00pm and instant change which is automatically reversed next day (for those that get daily sun times off internet).

Answer (score 4):

Standard (vanilla) Ubuntu nowadays uses the GNOME desktop environment (DE) which provides the "*Night Light*" feature whereas the "*Night Colour*" option is from KDE (you've also mentioned the screenshots are from KDE version of Manjaro). Different DEs are not always like-for-like replacements of each other.

However, you can control the colour temperature of Night Light following this Q&A: "*[How do I adjust the hue (intensity) of GNOME Night Light?](https://askubuntu.com/q/914500/480481)*". The [**Night Light Slider**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1276/night-light-slider/) GNOME Shell extension (as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/986716/480481)) also offers options to always enable the Night Light feature, sync the brightness slider with the Night light slider etc.
[image: Night Light Slider options]

But if you want an identical GUI, you may switch to the [**Kubuntu**](https://kubuntu.org/) flavour of Ubuntu which uses KDE instead of GNOME.

Comment: Well, I may switch to Kubuntu then

Comment: I tried out KUbuntu, but didn't like. I prefer to use Ubuntu even if its Nigh Color doesn't have many features as Kubuntu's Night Light

Comment: It's unclear how brightness for `intel_backlight` hardware settings or `xrandr` software settings are handled. Not to mention it doesn't show different settings for daytime and nighttime.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix None of these were asked in the question.

Comment: @pomsky That is true. Your answer does say *"sync the brightness slider with the Night light slider etc."* which led me to look into the links out of curiosity how it was handled.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Ah, I see. That's just an extra feature provided by the extension mentioned in the answer. It lets the user increase/decrease the screen brightness simultaneously with the Night Light temperature slider. I don't personally find this feature useful either.