# How to schedule multiple Night Lights?

Tags: night-light

I just installed standard Ubuntu.  I see Settings > Night Light.  I see I can set 1 schedule.  I'd like to set a more complex schedule with different Color Temperatures at different times of day.  Effectively customizing the "Day Light" in addition to the "Night Light".  That is, I want to run a weaker Night Light at day and a stronger Night Light at night.

Comment: In that case you must create a script with cron job..

Comment: How do I do that?  First, I would like to see the existing Night Light code but I can't seem to find it.  I searched online repositories of Ubuntu and Debian but can't find it.  I want to start by tweaking the interface in a very basic way, such as by changing "Color Temperature" to "hello world" or something very trivial as a test

Comment: Here's how to change the temperature by a command: https://askubuntu.com/a/914601/480481 (you can also get the current value using the `gsettings get` command).

Comment: How can I browse the OS source code to see all the places that `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-temperature` or similar are used?  I want to find the interface for Settings>Night Light and tweak it.  So more generally: how do I browse the OS source code?  It should be directly on my system, right?